# Using Ajax, to work with a mysql database to download files from server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I have created a table in my database called 'coursework'I am trying to create a button that downloads the files from the 'coursework' field inside the 'coursework' table in the database to the users computer. I have created the following php code:

```
include 'connection.php'; //This calls up the database 

$user = $_GET['user'];

$query  = "SELECT coursework FROM coursework where b_code = '".$user."'" ;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Invalid query');

$count = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo '{"coursework_number":'.json_encode($count[0]).'}';
?>
```

The mysql statement does retrieve the file from the database because I have tested the query in phpMyAdmin. my problem is i am trying to get the file to download via a button using jquery/ajax. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: What file extension are you trying to download from coursework?

Comment: what type is your `coursework` column?

Comment: You might not be finished yet, but i'd like to you make aware of the hackability of your code. It isn't that hard to delete your entire database with the current way you handle your input. NEVER TRUST THE END USER. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for escaping.. also there is a service named OWASP which identifies the top 10 most dangerous security threats for your software. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Comment: I am trying to download a pdf. The biggest problem is the probably the way the table has been setup. It was another team member who set it up and unfortunately there is no time to change it. The type of the column is 'varchar'. I am not sure if there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the security tips i will check them out!

Comment: I have updated my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20516981/2076351 with a possible solution, could you test if that would work for you? If not, tell us whats wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch this json asynchronously using jQuery.
See: [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

There are severals ways you could use for obtaining JSON from a server.

A few methods are provided with the JQuery Framework.

`$.get`, `$.getJSON`, `$.ajax`, these allow you to obtain the data (a)synchronously.

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z78M9/

---

Replace:

```
$('#downloadButton').click(window.open = response.URL);
```

with:

```
$('#downloadButton').on('click', function () {
    window.open(response.URL);
});
```

---

By the way, I see you are trying to implement an onclick event into your 'success' function, consider the following code:

```
$("#downloadButton").on('click', function () {    
    $.ajax({ 
        rl:"download.php", 
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(response){ 
            /* initiate download using direct path to file */             
            window.open(response.URL);
        } 
    });    
}
```

On the button click event, it will trigger the `$.ajax` request which will obtain the value, and when successful open a new page.

> Your logic seemed to be translating to the following:
>
> When I have initated the ajax request and it went successful, append
>   an on click event which redirects the user to the new page.

Comment: I did try this but I know that it is no where near what I need to do:$.ajax({
  url:"download.php",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response){
    // initiate download using direct path to file
    $('#downloadButton').click(window.open = response.URL);
    console.log(response);
  }
});

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. It didn't work unfortunately I think the issue lies the information that I am trying to retrieve from my database I will explore an alternative method.